# can't login or reset password to openshift account

Tags: openshift

openshift will not let me login or change my password. i created an account under the free openshift version at which time i could create a test app. after logging out and then trying to login it responds with a bad credentials message(password or login). i try to reset my password but i don't receive a confirmation email. i tried recreating a new account and still did not receive confirmation email. i send various help requests to to redhat but all responsees are the same asking me to verify accuracy of information, check spam box, and other things. these are robot generated responses from redhat because they do no refer to my specific help requests. i am going to give it one more try with help here, but if no luck i will move on to other paas. we are ready to deploy and can't waste time with external problems.

Comment: SO is for general programming-related questions.  You need to contact Redhat/Openshift tech support and/or Openshift community.  For example: [OpenShift Online Support](https://access.redhat.com/support/offerings/openshift) or https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset your openshift login password:

1. ssh to openshift server with root account.
2. type htpasswd /etc/origin/master/htpasswd username
3. after 2nd step it will ask for new password.
4. no need to restart openshift service

eg: I have username called "admin2" then my command would be:

htpasswd /etc/origin/master/htpasswd admin2

Thanks

Comment: Note that the original question was likely about OpenShift 2. Current version is OpenShift 3. How you can password in OpenShift 3 depends on what authentication provider is being used. Using a local htpasswd file is only one of many options.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Red Hat Openshift v3.9.30, `/etc/origin/master/htpasswd` was not available.

Reset password using `htpasswd  /etc/origin/htpasswd anto`.

```
[root@ocp1 ~]# htpasswd /etc/origin/master/htpasswd anto
htpasswd: cannot modify file /etc/origin/master/htpasswd; use '-c' to create it

[root@ocp1 ~]# htpasswd  /etc/origin/htpasswd anto
New password: 
Re-type new password: 
Updating password for user anto
```

And login was successful through `https://ocp1.example.com:8443`.

Comment: Do this as the root user and not the normal ssh user that you used to ssh into the machine. The normal user with which you ssh into master node wont be able to find the file that contains the password. so just sudo and do it. You can also find out which authentication mechanism is used after doing sudo and checking the "IdentityProviders" in the file `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 8's MAIL application then check your Newsletters folder.  The new Outlook Windows 8 app has a fondness for miscategorizing important notification emails like this as newsletters.